# How do I get a value from a different model in django?

Tags: django, django-models

Im new to django and im trying to figure out how to set the value in a model = to a value in another model

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True) # This is the value I want
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    companyName = # I want the name here
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I've tried these but they dont work

```
companyName = Company.name
```

```
companyName = models.CharField(Company.name, max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Where do you want to access this ? on a post request? on instance creation? Can you add your view?

Answer (score 0):

`Company.name` will not work because `Company` is a class, a template for making many `Company` objects, each with it's own `name`, so which `Company` object, or *instance*, do you want?

You need to get the particular `Company` first, and then you can set the `companyName` of the `Product`, or, you can set it when you save the `Product` instance, assuming you have a `Company` instance in mind, since you set `null=True`, so obviously if `company` is `False`, then there is no `companyName`.

Assuming you have a `Company` instance already when you save the `Product` model you can do:

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    companyName = # I want the name here
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.company:
            self.companyName = self.company.name
            super(Product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

But, the next question is **why** do you want to even *have* a field called `companyName` when you have access to the `name` field of the `Company` instance anyway.  Try to get it by:

```py
# Get the Product instance you want
product = Product.objects.get(...)
# Then you can get the associated `Company` name like this:
print(product.company.name)
```

**Suggestion**
Lately I've been seeing many questions with something like:

```py
_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, editable=False)
```

Not sure why, since Django does that automatically.